# The Scala way of creating Spring Data JPA repositories

Tags: scala, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
trait PersonRepository extends JpaRepository[Person, Long] {  }


error: trait Repository is abstract; cannot be instantiated
[ERROR] @Repository
```

---

This little trait doesn't compile for obvious reasons. But how can I define a Spring Data JPA repository in Scala? (Scala 2.10.3)

---

A sample test case using scala-test:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
@ContextConfiguration(locations = Array("classpath:/moduleContext.xml"), loader = classOf[AnnotationConfigContextLoader])
class PersonRepositoryTest extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  @Autowired var personRepository: PersonRepository = _

  describe("Person repository") {
    it("should persist a person") {
      val person = new Person()
      val persistedPerson = personRepository.save(person)
      assert(persistedPerson.id >= 0)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data interfaces need to be interfaces :). Just make your repository one, and the infrastructure should be able to pick it up.

Make sure you set up the repositories correctly (either using `<jpa:repositories base-package="…" />` or `@EnableJpaRepositories`).

Comment: Well, I was hoping I could do something along the lines of Neo4J ;) Like trait PersonRepository extends GraphRepository[Person] for instance. But I'm not sure if I fully understand the magic behind this. Is there any possible way for some trait to extend a JPA CRUD interface in order to make the plumbing work like in Neo4J?

Comment: Still don't get why you insist on or even need traits. You can extend multiple interfaces and given the fact that you don't need to provide an implementation for those anyway, I wonder what's the actual reasoning behind this. Plus, I'd try to get it to work in the first place. So are you saying it works when using `interface` instead of `trait`?

Comment: Yes it works lovely. There's nothing wrong with what you suggested of course. Maybe I wanted to understand a little bit more why scala traits are good in SDN but not in SDJPA. Also I would prefer if I could keep the code base 100% Scala. Maybe I should ask this in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove @Repository

This is working for me:

```
trait CityRepository extends JpaRepository[City, String] {
   def findById(id:String):java.util.List[City]
}
```